P-Ch MOSFET excessive gate leakage
I am building a simple battery undervoltage protection circuit. It should stop conducting once the input voltage drops below a certain point. This should be achieved by utilizing a PMOS and setting the gate voltage with a resistor divider to select the critical input voltage at which the PMOS is not turned on anymore. Before building it, I designed the circuit in LTspice, which includes a specific model for the MOSFET in use: https://goodarksemi.com/docs/datasheets/mosfets/BSS84.pdf

Simulation shows satisfying results:

Green is the "output" voltage across the load resistor R3 and blue is the "input" voltage generated from V1 (in reality my battery). The gate voltage (red) is moving from ~800 mV to ~500 mV.
Since this was looking good, did a quick layout and lasered a prototype:
Ground is on top and the input voltage is connected on the bottom.

(please excuse my terrible soldering skills)
I tested various resistor values, that's why a different resistor is in the picture.
The circuit behaves very different compared to the simulation. The gate voltage node is sitting at very high voltages, even if I drastically lower the resistor R2. The shown circuit uses a 3.9 MΩ as R1 and 100 kΩ as R2. However the voltage at the gate is 3.5 V.
I connected a multimeter and measured the current from gate to ground (I shorted the gate to ground that way) and it shows a current of ~3 mA. This kind of current obviously cannot come through the path of R1, so it must be related to the MOSFET. Looking through the datasheet, it mentions a Gate-Body-Leakage current of max. 5 µA - this is a whole magnitude off my measurement. Thinking that the MOSFET is broken, I replaced it, that didn't change anything.
Am I missing something here? What can cause such a high (leakage?) current through the gate?
Update:
The circuit behaves as it should without the MOSFET. The diode test of the MOSFET pins yielded following results: DS: 0.6 SG: 0.97 GS: 0.92 DG: 1.3 - the others were open.
Solution:
A never soldered MOSFET doesn't measure the same. This prompted me to check the maximum soldering temperature for this part - its 300°C for 10 s at 1.6 mm from the case. I soldered everything with 330°C. I now tried again with low temperature solder at 280°C and the circuit behaves like predicted.
Another main probable cause for the failure is ESD - I did not follow proper ESD techniques and MOSFETs without built-in ESD protection are very sensitive to ESD.

Maybe the SOT23 part is actually something else, such as  a common BAT54S.
Remove it and check the circuit without it. If it is behaving properly then check then part with the diode function on your multimeter. It should measure open except one D-S direction - open in 5 of 6 tests, if I counted correctly, and <800 in the 6th.

The circuit behaves as it should without the MOSFET. The diode test you mentioned yielded follwing results:
DS: 0.6 SG: 0.97 GS: 0.92 DG: 1.3 - the others were open

Quite strange, and not normal. Does a never-soldered one, if you have one, measure the same?

I just tested that and a never soldered one doesnt measure the same. This prompted me to check the maximum soldering temperature for this part - its 300C for 10sec at 1.6mm from the case. I soldered everything with 330C. I now tried with low temperature solder at 280C and the circuit behaves like predicted. Thank you !

@Janik It is extremely unlikely that temperature was the issue here. Rather it is very easy to inadvertently damage the gate oxide when handling MOSFETs that don't have a gate-source Zener clamp included and you don't pay attention to potential ESD.

tobalt's comment rings true, even though your PCB looks pretty charred unless you were using a blowtorch it's difficult to damage a semiconductor to that degree by brief heat alone. Follow ESD techniques- at the least work on something dissipative like a piece of unfinished plain wood or cardboard and discharge yourself before touching the circuit (especially the gate).

Thank you for the suggestions, I indeed did not follow proper ESD techniques. The charring is initially from the laser and then darkened up even more from flux residue and IPA.
